# put together 4 rows of strings and count words

Tags: c, string

Error line is: strcpy( tmp, row1+ row2 + row3 + row4 );

I dunno how to put together all rows then count words?

I tried to make function then call it before IF but didn't make it.

Also i thinked about chaning char in int then show it in prinft , also tried to make a array then put all rows in that..

How should i do that?

```
int main() {

char row1[256];
char row2[256];
char row3[256];
char row4[256];

printf("4 rows of lyric:\n");
fgets(row1,100,stdin);
fgets(row2,100,stdin);
fgets(row3,100,stdin);
fgets(row4,100,stdin);

char *tmp[1000];
strcpy( tmp, row1+ row2 + row3 + row4 );

int count=0;
char *cur= tmp;

for (;;)
{
    while (*cur == ' ')
    {
        *cur++;
    }

    if (*cur == 0)
    {
        break;
    }

    count++;

    while (*cur != 0 && *cur != ' ')
    {
        *cur++;
    }
}

char a1=row1[strlen(row1)-1];
char a2=row1[strlen(row1)-2];
char a3=row1[strlen(row1)-3];

char b1=row2[strlen(row2)-1];
char b2=row2[strlen(row2)-2];
char b3=row2[strlen(row2)-3];

char c1=row3[strlen(row3)-1];
char c2=row3[strlen(row3)-2];
char c3=row3[strlen(row3)-3];

char d1=row4[strlen(row4)-1];
char d2=row4[strlen(row4)-2];
char d3=row4[strlen(row4)-3];

    if( a1==d1 &&
     a2==d2 &&
     a3==d3 &&
     b1==c1 &&
     b2==c2 &&
     b3==c3 ) {

            printf("1 = 4 and 2 = 3, number of words %c." cur);

}
else if ( a1==c1 &&
          a2==c2 &&
          a3==c3 &&
          b1==d1 &&
          b2==d2 &&
          b3==d3 ) {

            printf("1 = 3 and 2 = 4, number of words %c.", cur);

}
else if ( a1==b1 &&
          a2==b2 &&
          a3==b3 &&
          c1==d1 &&
          c2==d2 &&
          c3==d3 ) {

            printf("1 = 2 and 3 = 4, number of words %c.",cur);

}

else {

        printf("Nijedna rima nije pronadjena u strofi!");

}


return 0;

}
```

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting?

Comment: You use `strcat` to concatenate strings, not `+`.

Comment: What is the purpose of `row1+ row2 + row3 + row4`? To concatenate the strings into a single string? Perhaps you need to learn about [the `strcat` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat)?

Comment: And `temp` is not a string of `1000` characters, it's an array of `1000` *pointers* to `char`, which could be seen as an array of strings.

Comment: @LThode sure "invalid operands to binary + (have 'char' *' and 'char * ') strcpy from incompatabile pointer type

Comment: Also, consider that when adding two rows there is a risk that the last word of one row is combined with the first word of the next row.

Comment: Unrelated_ but how would you write that code if you had say 20 rows?

Answer (score 1):

```
 char * stpcpy(char * restrict dst, const char * restrict src);
```

The parameter you passed is not of type `char*`.

Also you can't concatenate strings using `+` in c. Use `strcat` or `strncat`.

As reply to user's comment :-

There are 3 things that you should keep in mind

- First parameter should be modifiable.
- First parameter has enough space to hold the combined string.
- No overlapping between first and second parameter.

With these 3 rules in mind those can be used.

Comment: yea but everywhere where i saw strcat function people using with declared strings 
   char str1[50], str2[50];

   
   strcpy(str1, "This is my initial string");
 
   
   strcpy(str2, ", add this");

   
   printf("String after concatenation: %s", strcat(str1, str2));

Comment: @jovkm.: Not necessarily. You can do it over dynamically allocated memory also.(as long as parameters are provided as expected by strcat) Check the manual.

Comment: @jovkm.: Use `printf`